# Finding the quaternion that performs a rotation

Tags: quaternions

I managed to find [this answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39206/rotate-quaternion-a-by-180-degrees) where Christian Rau says "axis/angle rotation (a,x,y,z) is equal to quaternion (cos(a/2),xsin(a/2),ysin(a/2),z*sin(a/2))"

Assuming I know what rotation I need to perform, how would I represent it? 
eg, finding the quaternion that rotates 30 degrees around the z axis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit** I got as far as writing out "(cos(15),0,0," and then got confused on z * sin.

Comment: A rotation about the $z$-axis is a rotation about the unit vector $k$.  And we know that $\pi/ 6 = 30^\circ$, but we actually want half of that for the quaternion so $\pi /12$.  Therefore the quaternion is $q=e^{\pi k/ 12} = \cos(\pi/ 12) +k\sin(\pi/12)$.  Then if you have some vector $v=\alpha i + \beta j + \gamma k$, you just multiply out $qvq^{-1}$ to rotate $v$.

Comment: That makes sense! :D Thank you @Bye_World!

What if you needed to do one rotation followed by another rotation? Like 30 degrees around the y axis followed by 90 around the x axis? Do you just combine them in a single quaternion 
eg (cos(15*45) + i sin(45) + j sin (15) 
or do you need to multiply them?

Comment: You multiply.  If your first rotation is represented by the quaternion $q_1$ and your second is $q_2$, then the combined rotation will be $$q_2q_1v{q_1}^{-1}{q_2}^{-1}$$  Remember that $3$D rotations don't commute in general, so make sure you get the order correct.

Answer (score 5):

To rotate about the $z$ axis (yaw) by $\alpha$ you need the following quaternion

$\begin{aligned}q = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})\\0\\0\\\sin(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})\end{bmatrix}\end{aligned}\tag{1},$

to rotate about the $x$ (pitch) axis you need

$\begin{aligned}q = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})\\0\\ \sin(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})\\0\end{bmatrix}\end{aligned}\tag{2},$

and to rotate about $y$ by $\alpha$ you need

$\begin{aligned}q = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})\\\sin(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\end{aligned}\tag{3}.$

If you have a rotation described by the Euler angles $(\phi, \theta, \psi)$ (in the standard order), then, the corresponding quaternion is

$\begin{aligned}
q = \begin{bmatrix}
 \cos \tfrac{\phi}{2} \cos \tfrac{\theta}{2} \cos \tfrac{\psi}{2} +  \sin \tfrac{\phi}{2} \sin \tfrac{\theta}{2} \sin \tfrac{\psi}{2} \\
 \sin \tfrac{\phi}{2} \cos \tfrac{\theta}{2} \cos \tfrac{\psi}{2} -  \cos \tfrac{\phi}{2} \sin \tfrac{\theta}{2} \sin \tfrac{\psi}{2} \\
 \cos \tfrac{\phi}{2} \sin \tfrac{\theta}{2} \cos \tfrac{\psi}{2} +  \sin \tfrac{\phi}{2} \cos \tfrac{\theta}{2} \sin \tfrac{\psi}{2} \\
 \cos \tfrac{\phi}{2} \cos \tfrac{\theta}{2} \sin \tfrac{\psi}{2} -  \sin \tfrac{\phi}{2} \sin \tfrac{\theta}{2} \cos \tfrac{\psi}{2}
      \end{bmatrix} 
\end{aligned}\tag{4}.$

If you are rotating your object about an axis described by the vector $u=(u_x, u_y, u_z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and by an angle $\alpha$ about that axis, then

$\begin{aligned}q = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})\\\sin(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})u\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})\\\sin(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})u_x\\\sin(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})u_y\\\sin(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})u_z\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\tag{5}.$